# How to do Drop Caps in a Windows 8 C# XAML App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, character, winrt-xaml

I'm working on my first Windows 8 app (C#/XAML), and I want to include drop caps at the start of a paragraph. Anybody have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `RichTextBlock` and `RichTextBlockOverflow` within a `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RichTextBlock FontSize="48" FontFamily="Cambria" Margin="12" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=o2}">
            <Paragraph FontSize="122">L</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. 
                Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit
                interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci. Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus 
                aliquet, elit magna vulputate arcu, vel tempus metus leo non est. Etiam sit amet lectus quis est 
                congue mollis. Phasellus congue lacus eget neque. Phasellus ornare, ante vitae consectetuer consequat,
                purus sapien ultricies dolor, et mollis pede metus eget nisi. Praesent sodales velit quis augue. 
                Cras suscipit, urna at aliquam rhoncus, urna quam viverra nisi, in interdum massa nibh nec erat.</Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
    <RichTextBlockOverflow Name="o2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Margin="12" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=o3}" />
    <RichTextBlockOverflow Name="o3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
</Grid>
```

which looks:

[image]